# Question on Tangent

Tags: circles, conic-sections, tangent-line

Suppose that C is any circle concentric with the ellipse E: x^2/16+ y^2/4 =1 . Let A is a point on E and B is a point on C such that AB is tangent to both E and C. The maximum Length of AB is?

Comment: Also mention what have you done so far in this problem?

Comment: I do not know how to proceed. Please send me whole solution if you know.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Segments]

Let C be $\frac{x^2}{r^2}+\frac{y^2}{r^2}=1, 2\leq r\leq 4$. The [dual conics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve) to $E$ and $C$ are $16X^2+4Y^2=1$ and $r^2X^2+r^2Y^2=1$, respectively. They intersect in $(X,Y)=(\pm\frac{\sqrt{r^2-4}}{2\sqrt{3}r},\pm\frac{\sqrt{16-r^2}}{2\sqrt{3}r})$, that is the lines $\pm\frac{\sqrt{r^2-4}}{2\sqrt{3}r} x\pm\frac{\sqrt{16-r^2}}{2\sqrt{3}r} y+1=0$ are the common tangents, where the $\pm$s are taken independently. For more on the intersect-the-dual-conics approach to common tangents see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2428815/the-common-tangent-of-two-tilted-parabolas/2429158#2429158).

The length of the four segments are the same by symmetry so let's focus on the one in the first quadrant. The tangent points $B$ and $A$ are $(\frac{ r\sqrt{r^2-4}}{2\sqrt{3}}, \frac{r\sqrt{16-r^2}}{2\sqrt{3}})$ and $(\frac{8\sqrt{r^2-4}}{\sqrt{3}r},\frac{2\sqrt{16-r^2}}{\sqrt{3}r})$. So the length of $AB$ reduces to $$\sqrt{\frac{-r^4+20r^2-64}{r^2}}.$$ Now it's a calculus exercise to show that the maximum is $2$ for $r=\sqrt{8}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving the problem is to take parametric coordinates as trigonometric ratios. For the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$, $A$ can be written as $(4cos (\theta), 2sin (\theta))$ and for the circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ with unknown radius $r$, we have $B\equiv(r \cos(\omega), r \sin(\omega))$. Do note that the angles are different.

Now we write the equation of tangent $AB$ in forms for both the ellipse and circle:
$$\frac{x \cos\theta}{4}+\frac{y \sin\theta}{2}=1$$
$$x \cos\omega+y \sin\omega=r$$
Since these represent the same line, $\cos\omega=\frac{r}{4}\cos\theta$ and $\sin\omega = \frac{r}{2}\sin\theta$.

Writing the expression for distance $AB$ ($d$):
$$d^2 = (r \cos\omega - 4 \cos\theta)^2+(r \sin\omega - 2 \sin\theta)^2$$
which reduces to (by substituting $\cos\omega$ and $\sin\omega$ with $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$):
$$d^2 = 12\cos^2\theta + 4 - r^2$$

Now because the point $(r \cos\omega, r \sin\omega)\equiv(\frac{r^2}{4}\cos\theta, \frac{r^2}{2}\sin\theta)$ lies on the circle, we can say that:
$$\frac{r^4}{16}\cos^2\theta + \frac{r^4}{4}\sin^2\theta = r^2$$
which reduces to
$$r^2 = \frac{16}{3 \sin^2\theta + 1}$$

Now we can either replace $\cos\theta$ (which we can get from simple trigonometric manipulation of the fraction above) in the expression for $d^2$ and maximise it as a function of $r$. Or we could do it in terms of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve this using the slope form of tangents.
The equation of tangent to ellipse:
$$y=mx\pm {\sqrt{ 16m^2+4}}$$
This is also tangent to the circle of radius $r$ and then the perpendicular distance from the origin to tangent is $r$
$$r=\frac{\vert\sqrt {(16m^2+4)}\vert}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$
$$r^2=\frac{(16m^2+4)}{1+m^2}$$
The point of intersection of the tangent to the ellipse is given by:
$$(x', y')=(\frac{\pm16m}{\sqrt{16m^2+4}},\frac{\pm4}{\sqrt{16m^2+4}})$$
Now the length of the tangent between the circle and the ellipse is given by
$$L=\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2-r^2}$$
Now when we put all the values of x', y' and r we will get an equation in $m$ (slope) only.
For maximum length, $\frac{dL}{dm}= 0$.
$$\frac{d}{dm}\sqrt{\frac {256m^2}{16m^2+4}+\frac{16}{16m^2+4}-\frac{16m^2+4}{1+m^2}}=0$$
Putting this condition and solving, we get $$m=\pm \frac { 1}{\sqrt2}$$
And then put it back in the length equation to get AB as 2.